# Black bit in olive oil

Tags: food-safety, olive-oil

Should I be concerned about a tiny black bit in my olive oil? I thought maybe something fell into it or perhaps it's a bit of olive sediment. It looks like a very tiny flake of something the size of a tiny bit of dried herb. Is that a problem? I keep thinking that anything left in oil is a bad thing food safety-wise.

Comment: Could be a bit of olive.  Can you [edit] your question and add a picture???  **;-)**

Comment: @Fabby it's so tiny it might not show up in a picture, it's smaller than a sesame seed but thin like a herb. Does it matter if there is a tiny bit of olive left in oil?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your [additional comment](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/92368/black-bit-in-olive-oil?noredirect=1#comment145763_92368) it's very probably a slice of olive skin and as high-quality olives are preserved in virgin olive oil, this will most likely not make any difference to the food safety nor taste of your product.

Having said that, without a biochemical analysis of the speck we cannot be 100% sure and it *could* be a speck of [Black Nightshade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solanum_nigrum), but the odds *against that* are enormous.

<sub><sup>Though not *zero*...</sup></sub>

Comment: Thank you @Fabby. I was thinking more in terms of how garlic, etc. shouldn't stay in oil. But tiny olive bits are okay it seems?

Comment: @padma Yes, indeed.